# Spawning nodes with random time interval in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, ios, sprite-kit

I want to spawn objects with random time interval (from 1 to 3 seconds).

I've wrote this function:

```
func scheduleAddingLiquid() {
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(getRandomNumber(1, end: 3)))
        let block = SKAction.runBlock({
            [unowned self] in

            let liquidNode = LiquidNode(texture: self.liquidTexture, sceneFrame: self.frame) // It's subclass of sprite node
            self.addChild(liquidNode)

            self.scheduleAddingLiquid()
        })

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, block])
        runAction(sequence)
    }
```

Is it a good practice?

Comment: And how do you intend to stop the spawning?

Comment: I can tell you one thing I do not like is passing scene frame into liquid node like that

Comment: @nhgrif I'll add the flag later

Comment: @Knight0fDragon it's for position calculation

Comment: It is still most likely a terrible design you have laid out